# Script Error in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to set values depending on the chosen variable of lightning-combobox so i created the following javascript

```js
get timing() {
        return [
            { label: 'Weekly', value:'weely' },
            { label: 'Monthly', value:'monthly'},
            { label: 'Code',value:'code' },
        ];
    }

    handleMonthChange(event){
        this.month=event.target.value;
    }
    handleDoWChange(event){
        this.DoW=event.target.value;
    }
    handleTimingChange(){
    if (this.template.querySelector('timing').value="weekly"){
        this.minute='0';
        this.hour='0';
        this.DoM='*';
    }
    else if(this.template.querySelector('timing').value="monthly"){
        this.minute='0';
        this.hour='0';
        this.DoM='1';
        this.month='*';
        this.DoW='* ';
    }
    else{
        this.minute='0';
        this.hour='0';
        this.DoM='1';
        this.DoW='1';
        this.month='1';

    }
}
```

All values are already tracked. And the function that are not mentioned here for handling changes also work. The only I am having is with these functions but i can't detect where i did the error.

Edit: The page is functioning normally but when i select anything from the combobox for example - code, weekly or monthly - I get an alert that says error and with a text field to explain how i got the error

Comment: Can you provide a playground link with reproducible error?? And can you add exact verbatim of the error message?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal these are the things i can see additionaly in the error 
```[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu26/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:903:85
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu26/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:903:278
m.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu26/auraFW/javascript/dOMRLHt4yryfVjId3qhSww/aura_prod.js:12:5396
m.handleSelect()@https://curious-hawk-48tqce-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/combobox.js:2:4850```

Answer (score 2):

if condition should be a comparison.

```
this.template.querySelector('timing').value==="weekly"
this.template.querySelector('timing').value==="monthly"
```

It should be === instead of=.
Note: = is for assignment, == is for comparison without datatype comparison ("89"==89) and === is for comparison with datatype comparison("89"!=89).

**Important:**
Install extensions for LWC in vs-code (eslint, lwc-extensions etc). With these extensions you would have known about this problem immediately.

Comment: I didnt notice i was missing that. But i'm getting the same alert appearing

Comment: error is from handleSelect(), can you show that method also here? (did you implement it?)

Comment: no I didn't implement it

Comment: so thats the error

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I've encountered this error when firing an event from a child LWC to its parent.

At first the event was working. After some changes within the child LWC(without modifying the event piece) the event stopped working. I had to change the name of the event in the child LWC and the parent LWC and everything worked again.

**Child LWC method that fires the event**

```
handlePlusSign(evt) {
    const event = new CustomEvent('displaymyvalue', {
        detail: {
            myValue: 'Some value',
        }
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

**Parent LWC that hosts the child**

```
<c-child-component ondisplaymyvalue={handleTheValue}></c-child-component>
```

What I had to do is change the name of the event in the child LWC from `displaymyvalue` to `displaymyvaluenew` and then change the parent LWC's code to `<c-child-component ondisplaymyvaluenew={handleTheValue}></c-child-component>`. Afterwards the event started working again.

I'm not sure what's causing this but I have experienced it twice already. I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript debugging feature [in the chrome](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/debug-your-lightning-web-components.html). I had the same issue where I receive the values and try to iterate using a for loop but then I changed the traditional for loop to `for(let index in event.detail.data)` to solve